# A better code to see if python.email.message.Message part is an attachment

Tags: python, email

I have an instance of a python.email.message.Message
with 3 parts, but only one is an attachment

assuming msg is the Message, the following code:

```
for part in msg.walk():
    print part.get_param('attachment', 'noattachment', 'Content-Disposition')
```

will print '' or noattachment since the header is:

> Content-Disposition: attachment;
>    filename="abc.zip"

there is a more elegant way more friendly so I can also use reduce() to count them?

Answer (score 0):

```
matching_parts = filter(lambda part: \
  part.get_all('Content-Disposition', [None])[0] == 'attachment', msg.walk())
print len(matching_parts)
```

Comment: it doesn't work
your code (perhaps similar) returns []

while
for part in msg.walk(): print part.get_param('attachment', 'noattachment', 'Content-Disposition') == ''

False False True